# Android: How can I get string array from SharedPreferences for ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, string, listview, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter

I created SharedPreferences. It gets values from ArrayList and it saves values.

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("List", TextUtils.join(",", arrayList));
    editor.commit();
```

Then, I want to get these values in array of String because it requires to be array for ArrayAdapter. After ArrayAdapter, I want to print saved values for ListView.

```
       String [] serialized = sharedPref.getString("List", null); // This is not right.
    arrayList = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ","));

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, serialized);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

How can I get string array from SharedPreferences for ArrayAdapter?

Comment: the return will be simply a `String` and not a `String[]`. Use the `String` to set your `ArrayList` later with your method TextUtils.split

Comment: I think all you may need to do is use `String serialized` instead of `String[] serialized`, as vinitius notes. SharedPrefs is just storing a String and not an array or collection. Once you have that string, you then split it into the collection, as you are already doing.

Comment: It requires array. If I use a simply String, ArrayAdapter has error: "Cannot resolve constructor..."

Comment: Get the `String` from your SharedPrefs. After this, turn your String in a String[] and then pass it to your adapter

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: have you tried `String serialized = sharedPref.getString("List", null);arrayList = Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(serialized, ","));` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but again error: "Incompatible types. Required: java.util.Arraylist Found: java.util.List"

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper: then declare `arrayList` as `List arrayList;`

Comment: I just declared. Codes are okey but no saved values.

Comment: what's the value inside your sharedPrefs? Is it saved there?

Comment: @vinitius I didn't understand. A entered value will be add to ArrayList with EditText. Then, the value will be saved by ShadredPreferences and get value in String. After this, the string will be add new list. Then, the list will be print to ListView by ArrayAdapter. This form can be faulty or unnecessary long, so I am not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Did you manage to do what you wanted?

Comment: @vinitius Okey, no problem. "arrayList.add(listView.getCount() - 1, str1);" is not running. Thank you for helping.